# How to show my application's package name folder in Android/data folder in all devices like others application(such as whatspp,shareit)

Tags: android, sqlite

I am creating an application in which i want to show my application's package name's folder in which my database is stored in Android/data folder in the real device.I have used read and write permission also but it is not working on the real device but when i am running this application in emulator i will able to see my database with DDMS. Can anyone help me how to show my database name inside the

> Android/data/com.app.testing/database

In menifest file, i have used this

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in my databasehelper classe

```
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";

// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
//        Log.e("TAG", "DatabaseHandler: "+context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath());
    File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME);
    Log.e("TAG", "DatabaseHandler: "+dbFile.getAbsolutePath() );
}
```

Thank you in advance please help me if you know about this..........

i want to create my application's package name like below image
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an application package name directory like below:

```
    String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+ "/Android/data/com.app.testing/database";
    File dir = new File(extStorageDirectory);
    if(!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdirs();

    File sqliteFile = new File(dir, fileName); // your sqlite file name like "myDb.sqlite"

    try{
        sqliteFile.createNewFile();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this function getPackageName();

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    File dir = new File("Android/data/your location");  // define your folder location 
try{
  if(dir.mkdir()) {
     System.out.println("Directory created");
  } else {
     System.out.println("Directory is not created");
  }
}catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```